# Can the Inactive Salesforce to Salesforce Connection be removed?

Tags: salesforce-to-salesforce

In our Salesforce Org, there are about 5 inactive Salesforce to Salesforce Connections. These were created but never used. Is there a way to remove them completely, like deleting these, as they clutter the list.

Alternatively, can an Inactive connection be activated ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to delete completely inactive Salesforce to Salesforce connections. Kindly review [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kKdAAAU) link.

Also you cannot reactivate connection in Salesforce to Salesforce. Request you to review and vote for this feature [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000km04AAA).

Thanks